# Loading data into fuseki server

Tags: jena, fuseki

I want to load .nt file into fuseki server which is running in my computer through http using jena.

I can able to connect fuseki server using RDFConnectionFactory but while loading I am getting following error.

500 - 501: Unsupported Content-Encoding
org.apache.jena.atlas.web.HttpException: 500 - 501: Unsupported Content-Encoding

```
def getConnection(serviceUri:String): RDFConnection =
    RDFConnectionFactory.connectFuseki(serviceUri)

def upload(graphName: String, path: String): Unit = {
    val conn = getConnection
    if (graphName.isEmpty) conn.load(path)
    else conn.load(graphName, path)
  }

val serviceUri = "http://localhost:3030/sample"
upload("","file:///F:/IdeaProjects/Knowledge-BI/dataset/data.nt")
```

server Log

```
[2019-06-09 14:22:56] Fuseki     INFO  [9] POST http://localhost:3030/sample/?graph=http://www.knowldegeBi.com
[2019-06-09 14:22:56] Fuseki     WARN  [9] RC = 500 : 501: Unsupported Content-Encoding
org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 501: Unsupported Content-Encoding
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractContentParameters(Request.java:460)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters(Request.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1029)
        at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:194)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ServiceRouter.chooseOperation(ServiceRouter.java:142)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ActionService.execCommonWorker(ActionService.java:118)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ActionBase.doCommon(ActionBase.java:74)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.FusekiFilter.doFilter(FusekiFilter.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:285)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:690)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2019-06-09 14:22:56] Fuseki     INFO  [9] 500 501: Unsupported Content-Encoding (316 ms)
```

file I want to upload is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bIoy_UyWXhLSlfQbN6ufpEz6RgM9u4l4/view
Server is  Apache Jena Fuseki 3.11.0

I just need to upload .nt/.nq/.rdf files into my local fuseki server without any error.

Comment: "Unsupported Content-Encoding" is some kind of bad request. The error comes from the Jetty server Fuseki uses. Bad data is one possible cause - such as files that  should be UTF-8 containing invalid UTF-8. Find the file causing problems: it is unlikely the serve Fuseki log has information as the requests didn't get to the Fuseki engine, the error may be from the Jetty webserver.

Comment: It is helpful to have a complete report such as any information printed by the server, the version of the software, and code tat has not been abbreviated - i assume your file isn't really called ".nt-file"

Comment: Hi @AndyS I am able to upload same file from Fuseki UI That time Log in Server is 
```[2019-06-09 14:30:51] Fuseki     INFO  [11] POST http://localhost:3030/sample/data?graph=http://www.knowlegebi.com/sample
[2019-06-09 14:30:52] Fuseki     INFO  [11] Filename: rdf.nt, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => N-Triples : Count=106 Triples=106 Quads=0
[2019-06-09 14:30:53] Fuseki     INFO  [11] 201 Created (1.693 s)```

Comment: The code does upload("",...) so is the default graph, but your new example has a graph name. 

I don't see why "Content-Encoding" is set. I also notice the log server has "?graph=http://www.knowldegeBi.com" but the upload via UI has "?graph=http://www.knowlegebi.com/sample".

You could also try "connect" instead of "connectFuseki". 

Other - the code is not closing the conn. In Java, it would be try-with-resource. You should at least conn.close (even if there is an error).

UI upload is different operation.